# Tensorflow: constructing the params tensor for tf.map_fn

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def lineeqn(slope, intercept, y, x):
    return np.sign(y-(slope*x) - intercept)

# data size
DS = 100000

N = 100
x1 = tf.random_uniform([DS], -1, 0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=0)
x2 = tf.random_uniform([DS], 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32, seed=0)

# line representing the target function
rand1 = np.random.randint(0, DS)
rand2 = np.random.randint(0, DS)
T_x1 = x1[rand1]
T_x2 = x1[rand2]
T_y1 = x2[rand1]
T_y2 = x2[rand2]

slope = (T_y2 - T_y1)/(T_x2 - T_x1)
intercept = T_y2 - (slope * T_x2)

# extracting training samples from the data set
training_indices = np.random.randint(0, DS, N)
training_x1 = tf.gather(x1, training_indices)
training_x2 = tf.gather(x2, training_indices)

training_x1_ex = tf.expand_dims(training_x1, 1)
training_x2_ex = tf.expand_dims(training_x2, 1)


slope_tensor = tf.fill([N], slope)
slope_ex = tf.expand_dims(slope_tensor, 1)

intercept_tensor = tf.fill([N], intercept)
intercept_ex = tf.expand_dims(intercept_tensor, 1)

params = tf.concat(1, [slope_ex, intercept_ex, training_x2_ex, training_x1_ex])
training_y = tf.map_fn(lineeqn, params)
```

The `lineeqn` function requires 4 parameters, so params should be a tensor where each element is 4-element tensor. When I try to run the above code, I get the error `TypeError: lineeqn() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)`. Can someone please explain what is wrong with the way I have constructed the params tensor? What does `tf.map_fn` do to the params tensor?

Answer (score 2):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086098/does-tensorflow-map-fn-support-taking-more-than-one-tensor). The reason you are getting this error is because the function called by [`map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/functional_ops/higher_order_operators#map_fn) - `lineeqn` in your case - is required to take exactly one tensor argument.

Rather than a list of *arguments* to the function, the parameter `elems` is expected to be a list of *items*, where the mapped function is called for each item contained in the list.
So in order to take multiple arguments to your function, you would have to unpack them yourself from each item, e.g.

```
def lineeqn(item):
    slope, intercept, y, x = tf.unstack(item, num=4)
    return np.sign(y - (slope * x) - intercept)
```

and call it as

```
training_y = tf.map_fn(lineeqn, list_of_parameter_tensors)
```

Here, you call the line equation for each tensor in the `list_of_parameter_tensors`, where each tensor would describe a tuple `(slope, intercept, y, x)` of packed arguments.
(Note that depending on the shape of the actual argument tensors, it might also be that instead of [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#concat) you could have to use [`tf.pack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#pack).)