# Tensorflow tf.map_fn parameters

Tags: tensorflow

I'm attempting to structure my parameters so that they will work properly with tf.map_fn() but most of the example documentation only discusses arrays or tensors of the same shape as function arguments.

Links include:

[Does tensorflow map_fn support taking more than one tensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086098/does-tensorflow-map-fn-support-taking-more-than-one-tensor)

My specific example is this:
I have some tensorflow function that expects [None, 2] and [x,y] as parameter tensor shapes.

Tensor A is of shape [batch_size, x*y, 2]

Tensor B is of shape [batch_size, x, y]

```
lambdaData = (tensorA, tensorB)
lambdaFunc = lambda x: tensorflowFunc(x[0], x[1])
returnValues = tf.map_fn(lambdaFunc, lambdaData)
```

From the tensorflow documentation:

```
If elems is a (possibly nested) list or tuple of tensors, then each of these 
tensors must have a matching first (unpack) dimension
```

Since tensorsA and B only match in dimension 0, I cannot stack or concatenate them; I have also tried creating lambdaData as:

1. A list of two tensors
2. A tuple of two tensors
3. A list of tensor pairs

All of the above result in varying dimension mismatch errors.  I would follow the recommended use as per documentation of placing all of the data into a single tensor, but because of dimension mismatching between tensorA and tensorB I am unable to.  Has anybody had any luck with tuples or lists of arguments for elems?

Answer (score 4):

A probably prettier solution is to specify the `dtype` argument (see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn)) of `map_fn`, e.g.:

```
tf.map_fn(lambda x: fn(*x), elements, dtype=tf.float32)
```

if `fn` returns only one float32 value.

Comment: `dtype` is deprecated in the latest tf version, instead use `fn_output_signature` flag

Answer (score 3):

Turns out tf.map_fn's error messages are horribly misleading; the documentation does not mention this in detail but you need the exact number of returns on your function as arguments if you pass a tuple/list of tensors. Easiest way to do this is to return junk and then only grab the first return value.

```
print(a.shape) #[batch, 784, 2]
print(b.shape) #[batch, 28, 28]
lambdaData = (a, b)
testFunc = lambda x: return <somethingUseful>, 0
returnValues, _ = tf.map_fn(testFunc, lambdaData)
```

works as expected.